# Problem with arrow keys in Midnight Commander under Mac OS X after update to 10.6.3

Tags: macos, terminal, midnight-commander

After updating Mac OS X to 10.6.3 the arrow keys do not work in MC anymore - instead of moving the cursor it types, for instance, B for down key, C for right key. Although, if I quit MC and try it in terminal, it works.

Has anyone experienced this problem? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Not very programming related, is it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just solved it. For me, it was not libncurses -- I tried libncurses from Mac OS X 10.6.2 and I also tried GNU ncurses (compiled GNU ncurses and subsequently and re-compiled and linked Midnight Commander (4.7.1) against the GNU ncurses). Both attempt were futile.

I even changed the Terminal.app, which did not solve my problem either.

Finally, I simply removed the preferences file for Terminal.app. Quit Terminal.app, delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist, launch Terminal.app and start Midnight Commander. For me, this worked like a charm :-)

I tracked the problem down a bit further. In Terminal's preferences I usually make a copy of the "Pro" settings and make two modifications to "Pro Copy": I set the background to solid black (instead of black transparent) and I want the window to close when the shell exits. Whenever I make these two changes, the cursor keys become incredibly slow in Midnight Commander. As long as I use the standard "Pro" settings, MC works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use this:
http://rudix.org/packages-mn.html#mc - MC version 4.7

Comment: This solution has worked fine for me, the new MC has no problems with arrow keys on Mac.

Comment: Rudix now is here: https://github.com/rudix-mac/rudix

Answer (score 0):

It seems Apple broke the built-in ncurses (a library used by terminal-based tools that repaint the full terminal screen). If you built MC via Fink or MacPorts, there are probably adjustments you can make to the build environment to make sure it links against the Fink or MacPorts version of ncurses, instead of the system version of ncurses.

More information here:
http://www.opensource-archive.org/showthread.php?p=199981

...or Google [10.6.3 ncurses](http://www.google.com/search?q=10.6.3+ncurses).

Answer (score 0):

Copying /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib from a 10.6.5 machine to the 10.6.3 machine solved the problem for me.

(This was done as a quick fix to get a specific ncurses program -- namely CGSecurity's TestDisk -- to work. Of course upgrading to 10.6.5 might be a good idea regardless.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the bellow line to .profile

alias mc='/usr/local/Cellar/midnight-commander/4.8.24/bin/mc'

Comment: Correct your spelling and https://superuser.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when running `mc` via SSH on a Qnap QTS from MacOS terminal, with arrow keys turning into ABCD letters. No other methods helped but what I've found on another site:

> `export TERM=xterm` before starting `mc` in the terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).