# Midnight Commander (MC) installer for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, installer, midnight-commander

I use MC on Windows and Linux and would like to use it on my Mac. Can someone point me to an URL where I can download a binary setup/install?

Comment: I always suggest visiting the site for the product before doing anything else. The [Midnight Commander Site is here](http://www.midnight-commander.org/). Yes, they do link off to that other site for the Mac version, but it's useful to know what is and isn't available.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't know of any official binary distribution of MC for 10.6, but like other Free / Libre / Open Source Software, it can be installed by MacPorts or Fink. I prefer MacPorts:

1. Install [MacPorts](http://macports.org/).
2. `sudo port install mc`

**Update many weeks later:** In [someone else's answer to another question](https://superuser.com/questions/126394/problem-with-arrow-keys-in-midnight-commander-under-mac-os-x-after-update-to-10-6/129147#129147), I found a site that does binary distributions of many open source packages for Mac OS X. I'd never heard of the site before so I don't know how reputable/trustworthy they are, but here's their binary distro of Midnight Commander for Mac OS X:

http://rudix.org/packages-mn.html#mc

Comment: sudo port install mc throws errors, doesn't install correctly.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Adding that comment here is not going to help anyone. Ask it as a Question or something. Include all the error message output.

Answer (score 69):

It's also available for [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) which is a neat and clean alternative to Ports or Fink. You might want to check it out.

To install Midnight Commander with Homebrew, type :

```
brew install mc
```

Comment: Got `You must \`brew link pcre libpng\` before midnight-commander can be installed`, and `Could not symlink share/doc/pcre` when I tried running the link command.

Comment: And how can you install brew in osx recovery? there's no ruby in there

Comment: Now it is in opt/homebrew/Cellar/midnightcommander what to do ?

Answer (score 4):

You can download universal binary installer package from this link: http://louise.hu/poet/?tag=mc

Comment: actually, since currently https://www.midnight-commander.org/wiki/Binaries points to Your page, and the builds *are* updated constantly, I reckon this is the "official" answer.

Comment: Not anymore, has been a few years and louise.hu is no longer the official one.. for the benefit of others who are still looking for mc, best to find the official port for OSX from the horses mouth https://www.midnight-commander.org/wiki/Binaries

Comment: Site is now dead.

Answer (score -1):

1.Install x-code

`xcode-select --install`

You should have `brew` preinstalled on your Mac.

2.Istall Midnight Commander.

`brew install mc`

3.Done. Simply run `mc`.

Comment: No idea what's going on, but on MacBook Pro @M1 brew install mc isn't working